# Create new table in existing module without affecting existing table data

Tags: 7, updating

I have my custom module `myCustomModule` in `drupal 7` website along with installation file to create table.

I Have already saved lot of content in table but I need to create a new table in same module without affecting the previous table data.

if I add something new in `.INSTALL file`, I have to uninstall and install module which will remove the existing data content from my table.

Is there a way to create new table for existing module without affecting existing table data.

How do I update my module structure without affecting previous things.

[or last option for me is to create a new module and have separate table but I dont want to create so many modules ]

Please help , I need to do it for `Drupal 7`

**EDIT**

I followed this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/150215) and tried below and cleared cache after updating my code

```
/**
 * Create new database table {new_table}.
 */
function my_module_update_7101() {
 $schema['new_table'] = array(
     'description' => 'Table for storing information about static media asset .',
        'fields' => array(
            'aid' => array(
                'type' => 'serial',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique aggregator static media asset ID.',
            ),
            'asset_title' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 255,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => '',
                'description' => 'Title of the static media asset title',
            ),
            'asset_file_path' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 255,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => '',
                'description' => 'CDN url path for asset.',
            ),
            'status' => array(
                'description' => 'status field for the static media assets',
                'type' => 'int',
                'length' => 1,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => 1,
            ),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('aid'),
    );

  db_create_table('new_table', $schema['new_table']);
}
```

It does not seem to update my table

Answer (score 3):

Approach to generate a new table without affecting existing table's data.

Declare the table structure in **hook_schema** because for any new user who will install this module later should get this table so we have to code it here in **hook_schema**.

/**
 * hook_schema().
 */

```
function my_module_schema() {
  $schema = array();
  $schema['new_table'] = array(
    'description' => 'Table for storing information about static media
asset .',
    'fields' => array(
      'aid' => array(
        'type' => 'serial',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique aggregator static media asset ID.',
      ),
      'asset_title' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
        'description' => 'Title of the static media asset title',
      ),
      'asset_file_path' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
        'description' => 'CDN url path for asset.',
      ),
      'status' => array(
        'description' => 'status field for the static media assets',
        'type' => 'int',
        'length' => 1,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 1,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('aid'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

For the users who have already installed the module and want to create a new table can write a **hook_update_n()** as below.

/**
 * hook_update_n().
 */

```
function my_module_update_7001() {
  $schema = my_module_schema();
  if(!db_table_exists('new_table'))
    db_create_table('new_table', $schema['new_table']);
}
```

Here we will get all the schema and creating the 'new_table' by using **db_create_table()**.

Hope this will resolve your issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this use case for why you should not call `hook_schema()` from within `hook_update_N()`: https://www.drupal.org/node/150220

Answer (score 1):

See [hook_update_n()](https://www.drupal.org/node/150215), particularly the *Adding a new table* heading.

> 1. Add the new table to mymodule_schema() in mymodule.install.
> 2. Create a mymodule_update_N() function to create mytable 2 with the Schema API function db_create_table():

Afterwards run database updates and it will create the new table (example.com/update.php or `drush updb`).

Comment: I tried this link https://www.drupal.org/node/150215 , check my edit ... but it is not working

Comment: Follow the instructions :(.  First, be sure to add the new definition in `hook_schema` as well, or new installs of the module won't get the update.  Second, look at the example and what you're returning: `$schema['new_table']` does not exist in that scope.  Either change your definition to `$schema['new_table'] = array(...)` or in `db_create_table` specify `$table` as the 2nd param.

Comment: can you edit my code and give in answer ... thanks

Comment: do i have to add in hook_schema also ... I only added table schema in update

Comment: Add it in `hook_schema` like the directions say.  Did you run database updates as per the directions?

Comment: Also, if you ran the db updates while you had invalid code, you'll need to increment N in `hook_update_N` as it would have marked that update as having already ran.

Comment: after changing how the changes will be reflected ... I have cleared cache !!! it does not reflect